# Calling a SOAP web service from PHP

Tags: php, soap, service

I've never done this before so I'm completely in the dark.
I'm using PHP and I need to call a SOAP service running on a remote server that responds to a call with a status code. How exactly do I make a call? The service is running on a specific ip/port and it has a name, ie: http://1.2.3.4:1000/ServiceName?1234 where 1234 is a parameter I'm passing and for which I expect an answer from the service.

Please give me a few guidelines, thanks!

Comment: It depends.  You need to find out if it's a web service using SOAP messages or a web service that uses http verbs (Restful web service).  Is there a WSDL?

Comment: I'm told its a SOAP service. How do I find out if there's a WSDL?

Comment: Ask whoever told you it was a SOAP service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have `allow_url_fopen` on (usually true), it may be as simple as...

```
$response = file_get_contents('http://1.2.3.4:1000/ServiceName?1234');
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked right away.
I wish I could mark all comments as "Accepted" but I'll give credit to the first one chronologically. thanks ceejayoz and the rest of you guys.

Answer (score 1):

For very simple request/response sets, you can basically do

```
 $response = file_get_contents('http://1.2.3.4:1000/ServiceName?1234');
```

If you need to do anything "special", like authenticate to the server, log in, process cookies, etc... you'd be better off using [cURL](http://php.net/curl) instead, or look at the [streams wrapper](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-context-create.php) stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a SOAP/WSDL-Based web service, you should look into the [SoapClient](https://www.php.net/soapclient) classes as they'll basically do most of the legwork for you.

Otherwise, you can use a basic call to `file_get_contents` to grab the response of a web service into a string.

This would obviously only work if you're only doing a `GET` request, for `POST` and further requirements look into [cURL](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php).